# enabling ActiveX control in chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, activex

We are using WebTwainX in our application where WebTwainX needs ActiveX to be enabled it supports only in Internet Explorer. How can I enable ActiveX in Chrome and Firefox so that WebTwainX works fine?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. It is a proprietary, platform-specific technology. Only Internet Explorer for Windows supports ActiveX.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Google Chrome and Firefox web browsers do not support ActiveX controls. However, there are workarounds to enable ActiveX controls and get the required functionality based on ActiveX controls.
Google Chrome users can download IE Tab extension that acts as Internet Explorer emulator. It helps enable ActiveX controls in Google Chrome as it emulates IE by using the IE rendering engine directly within Chrome.Firefox users can install ff-activex-host plugin to enable ActiveX controls in the browser. This plugin makes it possible to use (host) ActiveX controls in Firefox and provides full access to the hosted control (events, functions, properties).

Comment: IE Tab doesn't emulate IE.