# javascript.window.open:open page only in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, activex

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

This code opens a page but with the user's default browser.

but

i want to open page only in internet explorer.

Is it possible?

i want to open page only in internet explorer Because i use Activex.(*is it possible that run activex in mozila?*)

Comment: WHERE do you execute that statement. And no, Fx does not natively support ActiveX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118868/enabling-activex-control-in-chrome-and-firefox - lastly, w3schools is a very poor resource

Comment: @mplungjanw:3schools is a very poor resource.Really!

Comment: Yes. Many mistakes and poor programming practises. They have improved a little since http://w3fools.com/ was created, but I still find many many problems in their JavaScript codes

Comment: So I repeat . where do you call this window.open? In a browser, from VBA?

Comment: Excuse me. in a html file

Comment: So you load this page in any browser and this statement opens in the same browser and you want it to open in IE? That is not possible unless you change the protocol and assign IE as the only application that can handle that protocol: `ieonly://www.mdn.com`. Also you need at least one more parameter on the call.

Answer (score 0):

the others are probably blocking the popup you generate

Try it on chrome and watch the right part of the address bar, you should see there a "Popup blocked" message

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can open a windows from one browser to other for security reasons or other issues.

But you can put a message in the page warning the user to use a specific browser if he is not using it. To know if the user is using or not IE you can use:

[Check if user is using IE with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie)