# JS/PHP : Email Compose and add attachment in Outlook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, outlook

I have created one portal where I want to configure outlook with the portal. There will be Email button where on click outlook should get open where subject, body and attachment should be added automatically based on data in the database.

I can open outlook and set subject and body but don't know how to add an attachment.

I have checked this link  [Javascript: Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229240/javascript-open-outlook-and-add-attachments-to-new-email) but I am getting ActiveX exception but I believe this is more compatible with IE. Also , [Microsoft - Outlook](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajnishkaushik/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=TestSubject&body=message%20goes%20here";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Outlook</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to add an attachment with JS, you can use the following code:

```
mailItem.Attachments.Add("your prfile url");
```

You need to set “Initializing and scripting ActiveX controls that are not marked as secure” to enabled.

In IE

[image]

[image]

This is the result of my running:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But we cannot change the internet settings. Is there any library or other way we can do this ?

Comment: Can you change the registry

Comment: No we cant. We cant ask customer todo that

Comment: IF not, you could use Firefox. Firefox users can install ff-activex-host plugin to enable ActiveX controls in the browser. This plugin makes it possible to use (host) ActiveX controls in Firefox and provides full access to the hosted control (events, functions, properties). Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118868/enabling-activex-control-in-chrome-and-firefox