# Use ActiveX in deployed MATLAB web apps

Tags: matlab, activex

I coded a MATLAB app which is making use of ActiveX to create a new Excel spreadsheet with some data. When I deploy the app for use on the web (via a browser), I get the following error when trying to run the ActiveX code (which is working locally when not deployed):

> Server creation failed. Invalid ProgID 'Excel.Application'

My question is whether MATLAB is possible to call the ActiveX code on the client, hence creating and opening the Excel spreadsheet on the client side.

Comment: Is ActiveX enable in your browser? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20996516/684399

Comment: Probably not, since MS Office doesn't look to be installed. I don't think I have control over that though. That is the reason I am asking whether the ActiveX commands can be executed on the client side (assuming the client would have an MS Office installation).